# Cypher query to get node by property not working

Tags: neo4j

I'm building a Neo4j prototype in NodeJS.

I'm running a Cypher query on my local browser to test.

When I run this query, I get this:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n;
```

[image: screenshot of graph]

But when I try to get a `User` by the `id` property, I get nothing.

This returns nothing

```
MATCH (u:User {id: 1}) RETURN u;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Eventually, I want to get the followers of a user using this:

```
MATCH (:User {id: 2})<-[:FOLLOWING]-(followers) RETURN followers.id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query below.  You need to put the value in quotes (string datatype) and remove duplicates when you return the id.

```
MATCH (:User {id: "2"})<-[:FOLLOWING]-(followers) 
RETURN distinct followers.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely cause is that `id` is a string. `MATCH (u:User {id: "1"}) RETURN u` should work.